# Replacing char in a String with Regular Expression

Tags: regex, notepad++

I got a string like this:

```
PREFIX-('STRING WITH SPACES TO REPLACE')
```

and i need this:

```
PREFIX-('STRING_WITH_SPACES_TO_REPLACE')
```

I'm using Notepad++ for the Regex Search and Replace, but i'm shure every other Editor capable of regex replacements can do it to.

I'm using:

```
PREFIX-\('(.*)(\s)(.*)'\)
```

for search and

```
 PREFIX-('\1_\3')
```

for replace
but that replaces only one space from the string.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just do a standard search/replace on a space?

Comment: It's because i only need to replace spaces inside `PREFIX-(' ...this... ')`. Other spaces in the text file must stay untouched.

Comment: Not sure how to fix it in Notepad++, but the reason it is broken is that each line is matching only once. Maybe run it through `sed` and do a "global" (i.e. multiple times per line) substition?

Comment: I don't know how you succeed to replace even one blank with your replacement instruction PREFIX-('\1_\3') . The first pattern PREFIX-\('(.*)(\s)(.*)'\) allows to find the occurences of PREFIX-('STRING WITH SPACES TO REPLACE') in a text, but even with only \1 in the replacement box, I can't obtain the slightest replacement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex search feature in Notepad++ is very, very weak.  The only way I can see to do this in NPP is to manually select the part of the text you want to work on, then do a standard find/replace with the `In selection` box checked.

Alternatively, you can run the document through an external script, or you can get a better editor.  [EditPad Pro](http://www.editpadpro.com/) has the best regex support I've ever seen in an editor.  It's not free, but it's worth paying for.  In EPP all I had to do was this:

search: `((?:PREFIX-\('|\G)[^\s']+)\s+`

replace: `$1_`

---

EDIT: `\G` matches the position where the previous match ended, or the beginning of the input if there was no previous match.  In other words, the first time you apply the regex, `\G` acts like `\A`.  You can prevent that by adding a negative lookahead, like so:

```
((?:PREFIX-\('|(?!\A)\G)[^\s']+)\s+
```

If you want to prevent a match at the very beginning of the text no matter what it starts with, you can move the lookahead outside the group:

```
(?!\A)((?:PREFIX-\('|\G)[^\s']+)\s+
```

And, just in case you were wondering, a lookbehind will work just as well as a lookahead:

```
((?:PREFIX-\('|(?<!\A)\G)[^\s']+)\s+
```

Comment: WOW. EPP's regex engine kicks some serious ass! I'm not quite understanding your regex, but it works. thanks!

Comment: seams that your regex also matches 
`<?php defined( '_EXEC' ) or die( 'Nope' ); ?>`

Comment: Well, it matches `<?php `, anyway.  See my edit for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep matching from the beggining of the string untill you can match no more.

find `/(PREFIX-\('[^\s']*)\s([^']*'\))/`

replace `$1_$2`

like: `while (/(PREFIX-\('[^\s']*)\s([^']*'\))/$1_$2/) {}`

Comment: which text editor supports a while loop? i have to do this in a text editor like notepadd++.

Comment: @Mike - Then the best you can do is find `/([^\s']*)\s(?=[^']*'\))/` replace`$1_` globally. Because you can only know whats in front of the last match position.

Answer (score 0):

How about using **Replace all** for about 20 times? Or until you're sure no string contains more spaces

Comment: i actually have to append something after the `PREFIX-('`Part, so repeating wont help here.

Answer (score 0):

Due to nature of regex, it's not possible to do this in one step by normal regular expression.

But if I be in your place, I do such replaces in several steps:

1. find such patterns and mark them with special character
   (Like replacing `STRING WITH SPACES TO REPLACE` with `@STRING WITH SPACES TO REPLACE@`
2. Replace `@([^@\s]*)\s` to `@\1_` server times.
3. Remove markers!

Answer (score 0):

I studied a little the regex tool in Notepad++ because I didn't know their possibilities.

I conclude that they aren't powerful enough to do what you want.

Your are obliged to learn and use a programming language having a real regex capability. There are a number of them. Personnaly, I use Python. It would take 1 mn to do what you want with it

Comment: @Mike So, if it is impossible to do it in an editor, what do you plan to do ?

Comment: guess i'll create a small phing script with some regex magic from above.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to run the replace several times for each space but this regex will work

```
/(?<=PREFIX-\(')([^\s]+)\s+/g
```

Replace with

```
\1_ or $1_
```

Comment: thanks, but this keeps replacing on and on. it's not ending after the closing bracket.